# How to get an array in laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel

Heres my query

```
$bbaplaukts = DB::table('materials')
            ->where('statuss', '=', 'Izlietots')
            ->orwhere('statuss', '=', 'Pasutits')
            ->leftJoin('bbaplaukts', 'materials.scanner_code', '=', 'bbaplaukts.scanner_code')
            ->leftJoin('alternatives', 'materials.id', '=', 'alternatives.material_id')
            ->select(
              'materials.scanner_code as scanner_code',
              'materials.reference as reference',
              'materials.description as description',
              'materials.id as id',
              'bbaplaukts.place as place',
              'alternatives.alternatives as alternatives',
              'alternatives.links as links',
              DB::raw('count(IF(statuss = "Izlietots",bbaplaukts.statuss,null)) as izlietots'),
              DB::raw('count(IF(statuss = "Pasutits",bbaplaukts.statuss,null)) as pasutits'))
            ->groupBy('materials.scanner_code', 'materials.reference', 'materials.description',
             'materials.id', 'bbaplaukts.place', 'alternatives.alternatives', 'alternatives.links')
            ->orderBy('bbaplaukts.place', 'asc')
            ->paginate(15);
```

And heres the result it returns

```
#items: array:4 [▼
      0 => {#1303 ▼
        +"scanner_code": "DM DS D2 D0"
        +"reference": "Metāla šķēres 20cm"
        +"description": "Metāla šķēres 20cm"
        +"id": 2
        +"place": "Bbaskapis"
        +"alternatives": "Test123"
        +"links": "Test123"
        +"izlietots": 2
        +"pasutits": 0
      }
      1 => {#1322 ▼
        +"scanner_code": "DM DS D2 D0"
        +"reference": "Metāla šķēres 20cm"
        +"description": "Metāla šķēres 20cm"
        +"id": 2
        +"place": "Bbaskapis"
        +"alternatives": "Test12345"
        +"links": "https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=talsu+riepas"
        +"izlietots": 2
        +"pasutits": 0
      }
```

As you can see they are almost identical, only "alternatives" and "links" are different. Is there a way in which i could get the query to return a single entry, but the "alternatives" and "links" are arrays of all the different entry's?

Sorry for the bad tittle, cant really think of a way how to phrase this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel provides a most efficient feature to achieve this through [Model Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships). However if you prefer to use query builder, you could try to delete 'alternatives' join from your main query and make it separately:

```
$bbaplaukts = DB::table('materials')
            ->where('statuss', '=', 'Izlietots')
            ->orwhere('statuss', '=', 'Pasutits')
            ->leftJoin('bbaplaukts', 'materials.scanner_code', '=', 'bbaplaukts.scanner_code')
            ->select(
              'materials.scanner_code as scanner_code',
              'materials.reference as reference',
              'materials.description as description',
              'materials.id as id',
              'bbaplaukts.place as place',
              DB::raw('count(IF(statuss = "Izlietots",bbaplaukts.statuss,null)) as izlietots'),
              DB::raw('count(IF(statuss = "Pasutits",bbaplaukts.statuss,null)) as pasutits'))
            ->groupBy('materials.scanner_code', 'materials.reference', 'materials.description',
             'materials.id', 'bbaplaukts.place')
            ->orderBy('bbaplaukts.place', 'asc')
            ->paginate(15);
            
foreach ($bbaplaukts as $key=>$bbaplaukt){
            $alternatives = DB::table('alternatives')->select('alternatives')->where('material_id', $bbaplaukt->id)->get();
            $links = DB::table('alternatives')->select('links')->where('material_id', $bbaplaukt->id)->get();
            $bbaplaukts[$key]->alternatives = $alternatives;
            $bbaplaukts[$key]->links = $links;
        }
return  response($bbaplaukts, 200);
```

Comment: Thanks!!! That's exactly what i wanted to get done!
Will try to experiment with model relationships to.

Comment: glad to have helped you!